# Can't get ios quickstart example to work

Tags: ios, google-identity-toolkit

I've attempted to follow the ios quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/ios/quickstart) and created a test project in google developer console. Everytime I run the similator (or on my phone), the sign in fails with the following error:

```
2015-11-03 16:33:48.236 GitkitDemo[29377:722944] Sign in button tapped
2015-11-03 16:33:56.300 GitkitDemo[29377:722944] error Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Unable to get user profile"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unable to get user profile"
 }
}
```

My repo can be accessed here if you'd like to repro the issue:
https://bitbucket.org/hbiz/identity-toolkit-ios-issues

Here are my dev console settings:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptswh48chyrjf6e/Screenshot%202015-11-03%2017.06.19.png?dl=0

Comment: Have you enabled Google+ API for your project in Google Developers Console?

Comment: that was it! thank you so much @JinLiu, you've saved me hours! The quickstart guide should really mention that necessary step